# Doctrine: Removing entity in self-referencing (many-to-many)

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, associations, entities, self-join

I would like to ask your help in deleting association.

My `User` entity:

```
class User
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="following")
     **/
    private $followers;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="followers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/
    private $following;
```

I have two actions:

**Profile:follow**

```
// followAction
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$me->addFollowing($targetUser);
$targetUser->addFollower($me);

$entityManager->persist($me);
$entityManager->persist($targetUser);

$entityManager->flush();
```

**Profile:unfollow**

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$me->removeFollowing($targetUser);
$targetUser->removeFollower($me);

$entityManager->persist($me);
$entityManager->persist($targetUser);

$entityManager->flush();
```

Process of following is working in a proper way, and I see appropriate records `friends` table.

But when I am trying to unfollow user, I receive exception:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO friends (user_id, friend_user_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params {"1":2,"2":10}:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-10' for key 'PRIMARY'

What am I doing wrong? I've tried with `persist` and without it, the same. Maybe something in association configs?

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is 2 persist actions, you only need one. Check this:

```
// class User

public function switchFollowingUser(User $user)
{
    if ( $this->following->contains($user) )
        $this->following->removeElement($user) ;
    else
        $this->following->add($user) ;
}
```

and controller would be just

```
$follower->switchFollowingUser($user) ;
```

Extract this method into two methods if you want but I kinda prefer this way because it is shorter.

Second thing:
Did you put

```
$this->following = new ArrayCollection() ;
$this->followers = new ArrayCollection() ;
```

in __construct() ?

Try if this works.